# How to translate the name of the action in a form validation with activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, routes, rails-i18n

I have a form, and the validation looks like the following:

```
Create
 - Nom/titre de votre objet doit être rempli(e)
 - Catégorie doit être rempli(e)
 - Description doit être rempli(e)
```

I would like to translate `Create` into something else. How can I do that ?

---

I am guessing I can add something like this in fr.yml:

```
activerecord:
    actions:
      create: "Création"
      update: "Mise à jour"
```

But that doesn't work. Is it possible that way ? How can I find the list of all translation keys that I can specify to active record ? I do not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question clearly.How ever You can try this.

In config/routes.rb

```
match "controller/Création" => "controller#Créate"
```

Comment: I just want to translate the name of my action, not refactor my code. I don't want to use non-ascii characters either. And I don't want to use non-resourcefull routes.

Comment: You want to display as "Création" instead of "create"in url right? If yes you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a gem that can do this work for you. Take a look at [rails-translate-routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes) and check their examples.

You can try [Dynamic Segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) as explained in Rails Routing from the Outside In, if you want to create it by hand.

Comment: It seems so basic... It must be possible without a gem.